# How to make iOS NavigationController style page navigation under WinRT?

Tags: navigation, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, pane

Assume we have 2 pages (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page).
page1 calls this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), ); to show second page.
How to animate pages so that outgoing page is animated to left and incoming page is animated from right?

Here's the current code:

**XAML file**

```
<Page>   
    ...  
    <Page.Transitions>  
        <TransitionCollection>  
            <PaneThemeTransition Edge="Right" x:Name="pageTransition"/>  
        </TransitionCollection>  
    </Page.Transitions>  
    ...  
</Page>
```

**CS file**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)  
{  
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New) pageTransition.Edge = EdgeTransitionLocation.Left;  
    else if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back) pageTransition.Edge = EdgeTransitionLocation.Right;  
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to replace the standard `Frame` control and use my [`AlternativeFrame`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/AlternativeFrame/AlternativeFrame.cs) control that [does exactly what you ask for](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/Views/Controls/AlternativeFrameTestPage.xaml). It has support for transitions where two pages are displayed and you can also preload the next page to make it open immediately when the user asks for it.

An alternative solution is to grab the screenshot of the current page using `RenderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync()` and display that in front of the root frame so as to hide it behind that screenshot, then navigate to the new page and when it's loaded - run an animation that slides the screenshot to the side while simultaneously sliding in the new page in place. There is no built-in support in the standard `Frame` control for cross-page transitions, but it's not too hard to build yourself.

Here's what an `AlternativeFrame` looks like:

```
<controls:AlternativeFrame
    x:Name="rootFrame"
    xmlns:controls="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"
    xmlns:Extensions="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions" 
    Extensions:FrameworkElementExtensions.ClipToBounds="True">
    <controls:AlternativeFrame.PageTransition>
        <controls:PushTransition
            ForwardDirection="Random"
            BackwardDirection="Random" />
    </controls:AlternativeFrame.PageTransition>
</controls:AlternativeFrame>
```

You need to use that with `AlternativePage` instead of simply `Page`:

```
<controls:AlternativePage
    x:Class="YourApp.YourPageType"
    IsTabStop="false"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</controls:AlternativePage>
```

You can then preload the new page like this:

```
await rootFrame.Preload(typeof(YourApp.YourPageType), null);
```

and navigate like this:

```
await rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(YourApp.YourPageType), null);
```

There are a few other transitions too and you can add your own, but `PushTransition` implements what you ask for.

Oh and you can pull the toolkit fro NuGet [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit).